# Moving from Flash CS5 to Flash Builder

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I'm now moving some of my projects to FB from Flash CS5.
I've got a question:

In CS5 when I wanted to add some images I just imported them to the library, put them into some movie clip, assigned it to some class `Image` (you know - this option `export for actionscript`) and then used code like

```
image:Image = new Image();

this.addChild(image);
```

How do I work with images in FB when I don't have a library? I mean that I do not want to load them from *somewhere* but i want to include them into my swf file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must export SWC File.

refer a following process.

---

1. **Export for ActionScript.**

[image]

---

2. **in Library mouse right click and `Export SWC File` click and name set "Image"**

[image]

---

3. **in your flash builder project make a `asset` folder. and your SWC files drag and drop or copy.**

[image]

---

4. **in your project mouse right click and Properties click.**

[image]

---

5. **Actionscript Build Path - Library Path - `Add SWC Folder` click and input a `asset`**

[image]

[image]

---

6. **you should following code Load a Class.**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    
    public class TestProject extends Sprite
    {
        public function TestProject()
        {
            var image:Image = new Image();
            addChild(image);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks in advance, man! Great answer. But, I can't get one idea. I can not create new `swc` files in Flash Builder, right?

Comment: This means I will need Flash CS5 anyways, if I want to import some images?

Comment: 1. right. only possible in `.fla`. easily say, SWC Files means Designer and Developer linked Item.

2. there is other way. but in generally using a SWC files.        also SWC .fla file packaging export is possible.
In your flash project `Publish Setting-SWC Publish` `OK` Click. 
this advantage is in Library A lot of Custom Class is only Single SWC File available. also is a easy manage and good productivity.